# EDU String to Regular Expression

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I want to make sure only students with a valid `.edu` email address can sign up.

Here is a way from the rails doc

```
validates :email, :format => { :with => /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i, :on => :create }
```

I am quite weak on regex. I threw `/\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i` to google and the test string is `launch@bacon.com`.

I have 0 regex experience. If the test string is `.edu` what will the regular expression be? you can point me to information that I can find to figure it out.

Comment: What is your question ? What is the problem ? what is the thing you can't figure out ? please try to be more specific ?

Comment: @Sniffer I am building a rails app and all of my users are students and I want to make sure only students with a valid .edu email can sign up. I need to validate the email address in my model with a .edu regular expression and I have no regular expression experience.

Comment: So you think the above regular expression has problems and want us to help you with a regular expression to validate emails ending with `.edu` only ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would implement two validations:

1. check for correct email format

`validates :email, :format => { :with => /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i, :on => :create }`

1. check for .edu domains

`validates :email, :format => { :with => /.edu\Z/i, :on => :create }`

Comment: I was so confused about the re that I put up, so it validates for email format correctness? I see thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with just one regex.

The following isn't a complete breakdown of how the regex works, but it might help give you an idea of what's going on. Suppose the email address is `me@mydomain.example.com`. Then:

- `me` matches `/([^@\s]+)/`
- `mydomain.` matches `/(?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)/`
- `example.` also matches `/(?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)/`
- `mydomain.example.` matches `/(?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+/`
- `com` matches `/[a-z]{2,}/`

So you want to change it so that the last bit, the `/[a-z]{2,}/` regex, can only match `edu`:

```
/\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+edu)\Z/i
```